# Firefox completes the address bar with content absent from my history

Tags: firefox, history, autocomplete

I have set Firefox to complete the address bar with elements from the history only ( other options are: nothing, bookmarks, and a history+bookmarks).

However, Firefox still continues to complete the address bar with elements that are no longer in my history. A search in the history returns 0 result for the incriminated string. How can I solve this without loosing my entire history? I have already tried <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> on the elements I would like to delete, without success.

How can I find the source of a certain completion ? (like an SQL request in the sqlite3 files used to store history)

I'm using Firefox 16.0.2 on OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Which version of Firefox, and which OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason, certain URL are absent in the history, but are still used to autocomplete the address bar.

The raw information is stored in a file places.sqlite in the Firefox user directory.

Locate it, quit Firefox, and run this command to locate places containing the URL you don't manage to delete within Firefox,

```
$ sqlite3 places.sqlite 'SELECT *  FROM moz_places WHERE  moz_places.url LIKE "%example.com%"'
```

The following command will remove the URL you want Firefox to forget:

```
$ sqlite3 places.sqlite 'DELETE  FROM moz_places WHERE  moz_places.url LIKE "%example.com%"'
```

This request is incomplete as it leaves the `moz_historyvisits` table inconsistent. Feel free to improve it.

Hosts are also kept in the `moz_hosts` table, in places.sqlite  and will be used for autocompleting.

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to the links found in your bookmarks.

Search the bookmarks once, and delete the items from there.

Comment: Are you saying to delete the bookmarks to prevent Firefox from searching the history?

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling autocomplete.

1. Open a new tab and go to `about:config?filter=browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled`.
2. Click "I'll be careful..."
3. Find the `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled` preference and double click it to set it to false.

Comment: But I want to use autocomplete..