# How can I ensure Firefox history is completely deleted after exiting?

Tags: firefox, privacy, history

I have set the option to clear my browsing history when I exit Firefox, but it does not clear completely. When I re-open Firefox, my History panel is clear but the address bar auto-completes websites which I visited in the past (and are not in my bookmarks). Old URLs must still be saved somewhere.

**Additional information:**

- I have disabled all my firefox extentions and still have this
  problem.
- I have experienced this problem with both firefox 20 and 21

Update: similar problem report:  [link](https://superuser.com/questions/495574/firefox-completes-the-address-bar-with-content-absent-from-my-history)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might provide you with an answer: [Locked or damaged places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locked_or_damaged_places.sqlite)

Firefox stores history and bookmarks in a database called *places.sqlite*. If this is damaged, deleting history or even adding something to bookmarks might have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

- In the Preference or Options dialog choose "Never remember history".
- You can switch to always browse in private mode, this will effectively do the same but you will be surer about it and won't need to change any settings.

Answer (score 0):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.default.behavior

This might be your article since it basically describes URL bar behavior that seems to describe your experience as an ongoing "feature".

I had to close and restart my FF to enable the change.

Comment: I read your link and options which mentioned there are easily accessible in firefox options menu and I am already aware of it. This is my problem: While I have cleared my history and History panel is empty, Why past visited URLs are still available in URL bar and where that comes from while history is empty?!

Comment: Well, this is drifting off into you didn't read, he didn't read.