# How to configure Mozilla Firefox 43 to forget everything on exit?

Tags: firefox, privacy

I know there is a dedicated Incognito Mode feature available but I'd still like to get this behaviour with the standard mode: clear the cache, local storage, cookies, browsing history and everything each time I close Firefox. Is this possible in Firefox 43?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I ensure Firefox history is completely deleted after exiting?](http://superuser.com/questions/596159/how-can-i-ensure-firefox-history-is-completely-deleted-after-exiting)

Answer (score 1):

Open Firefox **Preferences**, and go to the **Privacy** section. Under **History**, where it says "**Firefox will:**," choose the **Never Remember History** option.

Comment: What about "clear the cache, local storage, cookies"?

Comment: I have set it but does it affect cookies etc?

Comment: If you look right below that drop-down menu after you change the setting, you will see a message that says Firefox will use the same settings as Private Browsing. That is, this setting makes Firefox act like it's in Private mode without having to switch to Private mode manually.